# get multiple slno from dtVoucherEntry with same (amount)debit ,trantype and and set it to chcklist having same amount and trantype using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
foreach(Cheque details in chklist)
{
    decimal? trantypeValue = dtVoucherEntry
            .Where(entry => entry.TranType == details.Trantype && entry.Debit == details.Amount)
            .Select(tran => tran.SlNo)
            .FirstOrDefault();  
    if (trantypeValue.HasValue)
    {
        details.SlNo = trantypeValue.Value;  
    }
}
```

This is my codesnippet. I have cklist with trantype card and amount
1.two data with trantype card and same amount in chklist and debit(amount) ,trantype card dtVoucherEntry
2.two data with same trantype and amount varies.
i want to set slno of chklist from voucherentry

Example : voucherentry contains two data
Case 1
1.trantype- card, debit -50
2.trantype - card, debit -55
Case 2-
1.trantype-card, debit 50
2.trantype card, debit -50
Case 3-

1. Trantype- card, debit -50
   2 trantype- tt. Debit 55

Similar to this in cheque
Case 1:
Same case with trantype and amount respectively. I want to set slno with respect to these conditions in both and set slno of voucherentry to checklist slno

Answer (score 1):

**update:**
base on conversation you need to update slno in db from list base on matching cardtype and amount (can be many records).
at least its my understanding.
in this case you can do over linq
since i used linqpad its different approach to save record to db.
so you might need to adjust  SubmitChanges(); to replace they way how you updating record (EF or SP or ADO call.... etc..)
source:
cheqlist
[image]
db table
[image]

```
void Main()
{
    var chklist = new List<Cheque>() {
        new Cheque(){Trantype = "Card", Debit = 50.00M, SlNo = 111},
        new Cheque(){Trantype = "Card", Debit = 20.00M, SlNo = 222},
        new Cheque(){Trantype = "tt", Debit = 55.00M, SlNo = 333}
    };

    //find match
    var res = from t1 in chklist
            from t2 in DtVoucherEntry.Where(x => t1.Trantype == x.TranType && t1.Debit == x.Amount).DefaultIfEmpty()
            where t2 != null
            select new { t1.SlNo, t2 };

    //set db value for slno
    res.ToList().ForEach(fe => {
        DtVoucherEntry.Where(w=> w.TranType == fe.t2.TranType).ToList().ForEach(ffe=> ffe.SlNo = fe.SlNo);
        SubmitChanges();//use your way to submit change of DtVoucherEntry to db
    });

DtVoucherEntry.Dump();
    
}

public class Cheque
{
    public string Trantype { get; set; }
    public int SlNo { get; set; }
    public decimal? Debit { get; set; }

    public Cheque() { }
}
```

as a result db slno was updated with values from list
[image]

**original:**
**its not a full answer.!!! I try to create an example for you to provide some data. please adjust question.
also, please confirm class properties/column datatypes. and clarify your question what would you expect base on data provided.**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dtVoucherEntry](
    [id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL ,
    [TranType] [VARCHAR](20) NULL,
    [SlNo] [INT] NULL,
    [Amount] [DECIMAL](16, 2) NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

insert into DtVoucherEntry (trantype, slno, amount)
values
('Card', 0, 50),
('Card', 0, 55),
('tt', 0, 55)
```

[image]
and code

```
void Main()
{
    var chklist = new List<Cheque>() {
        new Cheque(){Trantype = "Card", Debit = 50},
        new Cheque(){Trantype = "Card", Debit = 20},
        new Cheque(){Trantype = "tt", Debit = 50}
    };
    
        
    foreach (Cheque details in chklist)
    {
        decimal? trantypeValue = DtVoucherEntry.AsEnumerable()
                .Where(entry => entry.TranType == details.Trantype && entry.Debit == details.Amount)
                .Select(tran => tran.SlNo)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        if (trantypeValue.HasValue)
        {
            details.SlNo = trantypeValue.Value;
        }
    }
}

public class Cheque
{
    public string Trantype {get;set;}
    public decimal? SlNo {get;set;}
    public decimal? Amount {get;set;}
    
    public Cheque(){}
}
```

**UPDATE: please confirm initial data: - if its incorrect - please comment what and where i need to adjust**
DB
[image]

Cheque list:
[image]

Comment: i want to set slno of chklist from voucherentry

Example : voucherentry contains two data Case 1 1.trantype- card, debit -50 2.trantype - card, debit -55 Case 2- 1.trantype-card, debit 50 2.trantype card, debit -50 Case 3-

Trantype- card, debit -50 2 trantype- tt. Debit 55
Similar to this in cheque Case 1: Same case with trantype and amount respectively. I want to set slno with respect to these conditions in both and set slno of voucherentry to checklist slno

Comment: one more case:1.trantype-card amount :50   2.trantype:card , amount:50, 3.trantype:tt , amount 55             same for cheques and voucherentry, i want linq to set slno in c#

Comment: i just added a field to differentiate cheque table data with same trantype and different and same amount sothat ican compare with that field and filtyer data

Comment: same above code use with extra condition to differentiate this ,its working thanks